# Best practice creating pandas columns within a custom function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pep8

Assumed I have a pandas data frame and a notebook cell where I add a column:

```
df[col_3] = df[col1]+df[col2]
```

What is the best (most efficient, most pep8-like and/or simplest, most readable) way to create this as a function within a helpfile `helpfunctions.py`?

My approach would just be

```
def create_col3:
    df[col_3] = df[col1]+df[col2]
```

but I am not sure whether this is even an acceptable way or whether there is a better way.

Comment: acceptable to who?

Comment: Acceptable as conventional proper programming

Comment: I feel that the question is too opinion-based for SO

Comment: @mozway fair enough, then it's at least not a completely horrible solution.